# Multiple Observables sharing single Error rxjs angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to handle API requests using Oauth2 authentication.

I have an `authService` with three attributes (`accessToken`, `refreshToken` & `refreshTokenObservable` – to be described later) and the `apiGet()` method which creates HTTP GET request with the Authorization header, like so:

```
apiGet(cleanedPath:string) {
  return this.config.getConfig().pipe(mergeMap((config: Config) => {
    
    [...] // Cleans parameters and creates a final query string

    // Adding access token as header
    let headers: object = {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this.accessToken)}

    return this.http.get<any>(cleanedPath, headers).pipe(catchError(this.handleApiGetError.bind(this, cleanedPath)));
  }));
}
```

I want the `handleApiGetError()` method to call for a new refresh token and try to repeat the `apiGet()`, where I tried to connect multiple `apiGet()` calls to the single observable, like so:

```
private handleApiGetError(cleanedPath:string, error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (!this.refreshTokenObservable) {
    // getAccessByRefreshToken() is simple HTTP post
    this.refreshTokenObservable = this.getAccessByRefreshToken();
  }
  return this.refreshTokenObservable.pipe(mergeMap(()=> {
    return this.apiGet(cleanedPath);
  }));
}
```

This, however, did not work as it called for the new token with every failed `apiGet()`, causing OAuth service to return multiple E401s (token was already revoked).

Is there any way to bind the `apiGet()` Observers together and in the case of error call the refresh token request only once with re-calling the failed `apiGet()` calls?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `retryWhen` to retry only once, and most importantly to inverse the control, so that your `ErrorHandler` is not responsible for retrying again (by calling its caller). 
 Using `retryWhen` your HTTP request will only be retried once the Observable returned by `this.handleApiGetError()` has been completed, as demonstrated below:

```js
apiGet(cleanedPath: string) {
  return this.config.getConfig().pipe(
    mergeMap((config: Config) => {
      return this.http.get<any>(cleanedPath, headers).pipe(
        retryWhen(x => this.handleApiGetError())
      );
    })
  );
}

private handleApiGetError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  return this.refreshTokenObservable;
}
```

That being said, `handleApiGetError` might be unnecessary as you can instead call `getAccessByRefreshToken` directly, as following:

```js
 apiGet(cleanedPath: string) {
   return this.config.getConfig().pipe(
     mergeMap((config: Config) => {
       return this.http.get<any>(cleanedPath, headers).pipe(
         retryWhen(this.getAccessByRefreshToken)
       );
     })
   );
 }
```

Comment: I tried to use your approach. Problem is it still uses separate POST request for each `apiGet()` call.